# Can I replace begin and end of an environment with a new definition with only braces

Tags: environments, braces

Can I replace the `begin` and `end` of an environment just with a pair of braces `{}` where the left brace `{` will take care of the `\begin{}` part and right brace `}` will function like the `\end{}` part? This is slightly similar to using `\centering` in place of `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}`.

See this MWE with the `alignment` environment below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\blgn#1\elgn{\begin{align}#1\end{align}}

% I want to define something like \align{} where
% the left brace `{` will take care of the \begin part
% and rigth brace `}` will function like the\end part.

\begin{document}
\blgn
  (a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2.
\elgn
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\def\blgn#1{\begin{align}#1\end{align}}` but don't do this.

Comment: `\centering{} in place of \begin{center} and \end{center}`  ???  `\centering` does not have a `{  }` argument and produces different spacing than `\begin{center}..\end{center}`

Comment: Seconding @DavidCarlisle, use an editor you like, which supports LaTeX, like Texmaker etc. where you have and can extend User commands. Saves a lot of typing ... // https://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/ // https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Are you recommending using `\newcommand` instead of `\def`?  You're right. I have corrected it. However,  hope you've got the essence of the question.

Comment: no I am recommending using `\begin{align}` hiding that in a macro only has disadvantages, but the code in my first comment is the answer to your question if you really need that.  I can not see any connection with `\centering` as that does not take an argument.

Comment: You can wrap environments in commands, as David says: `\newcommand{\olist}[1]{\begin{enumerate}#1\end{enumerate}}`. Then you would write `\olist{\item 1 \item 2}`. I think that is harder to maintain, though, because instead of a logical marker for the beginning and the end, you just have the bracket, which could mean a lot of things. This won't work with every environment, as there usually is some reason why an environment was provided instead of a command.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle can you maybe post your comments as an answer elaborating on why this is potentially a bad idea?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It's unclear what disadvantages you wanted to mean when `\def` is used. If `centering` doesn't seem to fit to the analogy, I can recall something from `beamer`. There both `\frame{}` and `\begin{frame}...\end{frame}` serve the same purpose imo. Anyway, following @musarithmia's suggestion I find both `\newcommand{\algn}[1]{\begin{align}#1\end{align}}` and
`\def\algn#1{\begin{align}#1\end{align}}` resolve my issue. Thanks.